# Error in test exception

Tags: python, python-unittest, stub

This is my dummy class that I want to test:

```
class Meter:

    def __init__(self, meterInfo):
        self.b1pos = meterInfo['b1pos']


    def setMeter(self):
        print 'Initializing'
        try:
             print 'Connecting'
        except IOError as message:
            print message

    def readSignal(self, ele_name):
        try:
            if ele_name in ("b1", "b2"):
                readValue = 0.0
                readValue1 = 0.0
                return readValue, readValue1
            else:
                readValue = 0.0
                readValue1 = 0.0
                return readValue, readValue1
        except IOError as message:
            print message
```

And this is my unittest:

```
class TestMeter(unittest.TestCase):

    def testSetMeter(self):
        m = meter.Meter({'b1pos': 'b1pos'})
        self.assertRaises(IOError, m.setMeter())

    def testReadSignal(self):
        m = meter.Meter({'b1pos': 'b1pos'})
        a, b = m.readSignal('b1')
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(a, numbers.Number))
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(b, numbers.Number))
        self.assertRaises(IOError, m.readSignal('b1'))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

For testSetMeter() I dont have any problems, but for testReadSignal() it gives me: "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable"
I understand that this error is related to the return of radSignal, but how can I fix it?
I tried with:

```
 def testReadSignal(self):
    m = meter.Meter({'b1pos': 'b1pos'})
    a, b = m.readSignal('b1')
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(a, numbers.Number))
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(b, numbers.Number))
    with self.assertRaises(IOError):
         m.readSignal('b1')
```

But this is the output:

```
AssertionError: IOError not raised
```

Comment: Can you show us class multimeter?

Comment: sorry i make a typo in copying, i correct the text

Comment: What is the real problem? The function is catching the exception, so it is ok the test fails to receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with

```
 self.assertRaises(Exception, m.readSignal('b1'))
```

I solved the problem

Comment: This is testing something else then, if you were after IOError exceptions, then it means it is testing something else. Maybe clarify the problem in the question.

Comment: You are right, I kept reviewing the code today. There are 2 mistakes: I shouldnt print the message in the class Meter, but instead raise it. and
self.assertRaises(Exception, m.readSignal('b1')) should be:
self.assertRaises(IOError, m.readSignal, 'b1')

Answer (score 0):

Have to use pytest.raises instead. See the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html).

```
with self.raises(IOError):
    m.readSignal('b1')
```

It also seems that the tests would fail since the methods are catching the exceptions, rather than raising them.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I used it, but it gives the same problem

Comment: If the output is: `AssertionError: IOError not raised`, it only means that the function is not raising the exception, which is ok really since the code posted in the question is not raising those, it is actually catching them, so it would not be thrown to the test.

Comment: Please mark answer as valid if it solved the problem :)